# Avoiding dirty-update in specify Bean with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Well, I'm using a web application with FlushMode.AUTO and i don't want to change this but now i need avoiding dirty-update JPA of specificy case.

I have to add a lot of objects into other, like: Father and Child (One to Many).

In each Child added to a Father i change a boolean flag in children:

```
child.setOrphan(false);
```

After this, i search for another child, but before search the JPA update in database the flag "orphan" and i don't want this, i need ensure that update child when user click on "save" in Father.

Comment: you can detach entity and after all changes merge it back again. But I think it is bad way. You can try get entity using query and set FlushMode.COMMIT on query, maybe it's help

Comment: Unhappy i can't use "FlushMode.COMMIT", because all my find methods have @Transactional(Propagation.SUPPORTS). So, I already try use FlushMode.COMMIT but when some find method is called the flush() is fired. If i remove @Transactional, this works, but my object continue in JVM MEMORY with "wrong value".